# FireFox issue with a flex element that has max width

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

Here is that example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVBNOE

```
.form-element__field-container {
  @include display(flex);
  max-width: 200px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-element__input-prepend {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.form-element__input-append {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

<div class="form-element__field-container" >
  <span class="form-element__input-prepend">
    <span>$</span>
  </span>
  <input class="form-element__input-container form-element__input m-text m-has-prepend m-has-append" placeholder="???" value="23.43" type="text">
  <span class="form-element__input-append">
    <span>this is long</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

In chrome, all the elements are contained with in the 200px width that is defined for the root element however in Firefox, the elements in the root element equal to 224px and overflow the root element's 200px width.  The biggest difference is that in FireFox the input element is 149px width but in Chrome it is 117px.

Anyone know what would be causing this issue?

Comment: Isn't it related to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1139931 ?

Comment: probably, did not see that bug before